# remove() not functioning correctly

Tags: java, arrays, hash, hashtable, double-hashing

In the following `Main` method why isn't the last word (`clapping`) removed?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HT ht = new HT();

        ht.insert("airplane");
        ht.insert("distilling");
        ht.insert("speaks");
        ht.insert("knit");
        ht.insert("digitize");
        ht.insert("Media");
        ht.insert("canonicalized");
        ht.insert("libraries");
        ht.insert("clapping");
        ht.insert("residues");
        ht.insert("spoilers");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ht.set));

        ht.remove("distilling");
        ht.remove("knit");
        ht.remove("canonicalized");
        ht.remove("libraries");
        ht.remove("clapping");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ht.set));
    }
}
```

The output is

```
[Media, digitize, airplane, canonicalized, spoilers, distilling, clapping, knit, libraries, speaks, residues]
[Media, digitize, airplane, null, spoilers, null, clapping, null, null, speaks, residues]
```

`clapping` is not removed. Why?

HT.java

```
public class HT {
    public String[] set;
    public int size;

    public HT() {
        this.set = new String[11];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public void insert(String word) {
        int hash1 = giveHash1( word );
        int hash2 = giveHash2( word );
        while (set[hash1] != null) {
            hash1 += hash2;
            hash1 %= set.length;
        }
        set[hash1] = word;
        size++;
    }

    public void remove(String word) {
        int hash1 = giveHash1(word);
        int hash2 = giveHash2(word);
        while (set[hash1] != null && !set[hash1].equals(word)) {
            hash1 += hash2;
            hash1 %= set.length;
        }
        set[hash1] = null;
        size--;
    }

    public int giveHashCode(String s) {
        int hash = 0, x = 31;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
            hash = x * hash + s.charAt(i);
        }
        return hash;
    }
    private int giveHash1(String s) {
        return  (giveHashCode(s) % set.length < 0)
                ? (giveHashCode(s) % set.length) + set.length
                : giveHashCode(s) % set.length;
    }
    private int giveHash2(String s) {
        return  3 - (((giveHashCode(s) % set.length < 0)
                ? (giveHashCode(s) % set.length) + set.length
                : giveHashCode(s) % set.length) % 3);
    }
}
```

Apart from the modifiers, is there anything wrong with the code? Probably with the hash functions or maybe with `insert()` or `remove()`?

Comment: Just curious, but where did you get this strange double hashing algorithm from?

Comment: You might want to step through your code with a debugger and look at the values. Since you're changing `hash1` while trying to remove my guess is the resulting hash is not the same as was used to insert and thus the wrong bucket is set to null. And I second Shadab in that this is a really strange hashing algorithm.

Comment: Additional note: since your `insert()` seems to try to avoid clashes by changing the hash until you find an empty spot that look might run a while, especially when searching for the last available bucket. This also would result in a different hash depending on the insert order and that will cause a whole lot of problems not only with removal but any other operation that needs to find a given word - you can't just access the word by hash or search a single bucket but might have to search the entire hash table.

Comment: Your remove function removes the first non-null entry, even if it doesn't match.

Comment: I see, what are some good hashing functions then? Those r a mixture of what i was taught in university and on the internet.Btw `giveHash2()` is supposed to use 7 in reality but i changed it to 3 since it caused less collisions. It would be great if a few good hashing functions are mentioned. I am trying not to use the built in hash class but rather implement it myself.

Comment: So, you would rather avoid something proven to work well? In the real world this is called the Not-Invented-Here syndrome. Don't rewrite something just because it would be fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely the terminating condition for the loop in the `remove()` method.

```
while (set[hash1] != null && !set[hash1].equals(word)) {
```

which terminates at the first `null` value it finds.

When inserting, you're updating `hash1` if the position is already occupied, so the final position of a word depends on the existing inserted words i.e. the occupied positions.

However when you've already removed a few of the values, the loop in `remove()` may find empty positions (`null` values) much sooner, and terminate before actually reaching the position the `word` was originally inserted in.

Comment: Oh i see, what could be a possible workaround then? Removing that `null` check from the `while` condition causes a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: When doing open addressing, it's usually a good idea to differentiate between "This position was always empty" and "This position had it's value removed". If you can mark a position as "This position had it's value removed" then you can treat it as empty when inserting and searching, but iterate over it when calling `remove`

Comment: thx! I just implemented it and it now works

Comment: Btw since u said my hashing functions were strange, could u modify ur answer to include some good ones which might cause less collisions